# How to update value of an attribute of an element, then trigger click on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-file-upload

I would like to use jQuery to update value of attribute "accept" of an input element with type = "file", then active the "click" event of it. But after the value of "accept" is changed, nothing happens.
This is my code

```
//html elements
<button type="button" class="abc" title="Select files from your computer" id="upload" onclick="updateExtension()"></button>
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" multiple="multiple" /> //this input field is hidden and is applied with jquery-file-upload

//jQuery function
function updateExtension(){
  $('#image').attr('accept', '.jpg, .png');
  $('#image').click();
}
```

Comment: try $('#image').trigger('click') instead of $('#image').click()

Comment: @PrasannaVenkatesh tried, same result

Comment: it is working as expected, what problem you are facing

Comment: @brk well I do not event know. When I click on the button, the value of "accept" is updated, and then since the type of input element is "file", it's click event will show up a file dialog but in my case it shows nothing and no any error logged in console.

Comment: Looks good, check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ynfo1n0a/   Do you see any errors in console?

Comment: Thank guys, I figured it out. It is due to the browser's setting is prevent displaying popup. LOL.

Comment: Guys how do I make the jquery click() function bypass the browser's popup blocker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use :

```
$( "#image" ).trigger( "click" );
```

For more information on jQuery trigger [click here](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Answer (score 0):

Simple way use this one:--

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#click").click(function(){
               //if update(div)content
               $(".update_new_value").html("<h1>Enter content</h1>");
               //if change attr value
          $("#urls_change").attr("href", "https://www.changers.com/"); 

    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="update_new_value"></div>
 <p><a href="https://www.anyurls.com" id="urls_change">change urls</a></p>

<button name="btn" id="click" type="button">Click Me</button>


</body>
</html>
```